# How do I add a retweet button to my WordPress blog?

Tags: twitter, wordpress

I have a free version of the WordPress blog and I've tried adding a retweet button while editing the post in HTML, but it doesn't seem to appear.

Any tips?

Comment: what do you mean the free version ? wordpress.org or wordpress.com ? Only wordpress.com topics are allowed here. Try webmasters.stackexchange.com instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [TweetMeme](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweetmeme/) plugin. Or any kind of social buttons plugin (e.g.: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fixed-social-buttons/)

Comment: it says I have to upload the plugin to the wp-plugins directory. Do I have to ftp to my site and dump the plugin there? I am only using the free online version of wordpress.

Comment: If your blog is hosted at wordpress.com (e.g.: myblog.wordpress.com), then see here: http://onecoolsitebloggingtips.com/2010/02/06/tweetmeme-button-shortcode-for-wordpress-com/ . If you host it yourself (e.g.: myblog.com), then yes, you have to download the plugin, upload it to the wp-plugins directory using FTP and then activate it from the admin panel.

Comment: Moreover, if your blog is hosted at wordpress.com and you want more than just twitter, see here: http://onecoolsitebloggingtips.com/2010/04/08/social-bookmarks-for-wordpress-com-blogs/